# Search instead filename

Tags: php

I have this script to search file into a directory.
Works well when i perform search with exactly term, example: "my file.doc", "sales order 1234.pdf"

Can anyone help me to modify to search word into filename, example: "file" ou "Sales"

TKS
Cris.

```
<?php
    if($_POST['search']) {
    $word = $_POST['file'];
    $dir = './';
    $list  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($list);

    $num = 0; //  
    foreach($recursive as $obj){

    //echo $obj->getFilename().'<br />'; 
    if($obj->getFilename()=="$word"){
      echo $obj->getPathname().'<br/>';
      $num++;
       }
      } 
    echo "found(s) $num file(s)."; 
    }
   ?>


<form action="" method="POST">
search files. <input type="text" name="file" value="">
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if($_POST['search']) {
    $word = $_POST['file'];
    $dir = './';
    $list  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $recursive = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($list);

    $num = 0; //  
    foreach($recursive as $obj){

    //echo $obj->getFilename().'<br />'; 
    if( strpos( $obj->getFilename(), "$word" ) === true ){
      echo $obj->getPathname().'<br/>';
      $num++;
       }
      } 
    echo "found(s) $num file(s)."; 
    }
   ?>


<form action="" method="POST">
search files. <input type="text" name="file" value="">
<input type="submit" name="search">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php) function or the [strstr](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strstr.php) function on your filename.

Test if the function returns something different than false to know your filename contains your chain.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) to count the occurrences of a string in another, but since you need one or more you can check like this:

```
if( substr_count( $obj->getFilename(), $word ) ){
    echo $obj->getPathname().'<br/>';
    $num++;
}
```

**edit:** for case-insensitive comparison:

```
if( substr_count( strtolower($obj->getFilename()), strtolower($word) ) {
     // ...
}
```

Comment: Hello Teneff,
Works Great, thanks...

Have a quick tip to perform case INSENSITIVE search?

Comment: Thanks Teneff, i'm new on this site and i not have 15 reputation yet, but asap rate you.

Comment: Teneff, I'm like to send you a private message, have you mail? or thru this site?